# How to display TOP result 10 in Grafana for influxDB?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable

I need to show Top 10 Nodes with most total GC time on Grafana with InfluxDB but not sure how to solve it. I have tried below things but nothing work.
1. We cannot use TOP function with group by as it is limitation of InfluxDB to get TOP result.
2. I tried to find to 10 using order by but it ORDER BY is only supported for “time”
3. I tried use nested query but it also doesn’t work it doesn’t return tag with it.

Please suggest a way to do it.